# Laravel query using LIKE does not return any result

Tags: php, sql, laravel, orm, backend

Hi guys I'm currently stuck in this issue. I'm trying to search something on DB and doesn't return any results. Below are my codes.

Search string 1 = Boston Celtics

Search string 2 = Boston Celtics Can't

DB post_title = Boston Celtics Can’t Let Bulls Loss Impact Difficult Stretch

**QUERY**

```
$data = $searchPost->where('post_title', 'like', '%'.$search.'%')
            ->orderBy('post_date', 'desc')
            ->offset($offset)
            ->limit($limit)
            ->get();
```

Search string 1 returns a result but search string 2 is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple, because your searching different string.

Search String 2 ".. Can't .." use **Straight Quotes**.

> '

DB post_title ".. Can’t .." use **Curly Quotes**.

> ’

For reference: [Straight and curly quotes](https://practicaltypography.com/straight-and-curly-quotes.html)

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that an apostrophe might be to blame - in SQL Server the concatenation operator is "+" so you also might want to make sure that is right.  Maybe try removing an apostrophe character with:

replace($search, '''', '')

Four single quotes in Microsoft SQL is an escape sequence for a single quote.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

1) You code might be breaking string because of `'` in `can't`.

```
$data = $searchPost->where('post_title', 'like', "%{$search}%")
            ->orderBy('post_date', 'desc')
            ->offset($offset)
            ->limit($limit)
            ->get();
```

Comment: might be breaking it on the 'db' side, not the PHP side ... `"%{$search}%" === '%'. $search .'%'`

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem before

try this

```
$data = $searchPost->where('post_title', 'like', '"%'.$search.'%"')
        ->orderBy('post_date', 'desc')
        ->offset($offset)
        ->limit($limit)
        ->get();
```

as you can see there is a " before 
the % at the start and another after % in the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you see carefully you Can't in your search and your DB, the `'` does not look the same

Can’t
vs 
Can't

When the ' is not the same, sure it can't be searched. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

Had to use str_replace method to change apostrophe character

```
$search = str_replace('-', ' ', urldecode($request->input('search')));
$search = str_replace("'", "’", $search);
```