# Special Characters and Searches with Laravel 3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

I am using a grid to display businesses. I'm going to strip down our laravel call to bare minimum so lets say I have about 20,000 businesses and I don't want to load them all if I don't need to. So I am showing a search bar before the grid is loaded to type and query and based on their search input, I load what matches using Laravel into the grid.

The issue I am having is with Special Characters. If in the DB I have a Business Name of Lucky's Bar, and the users search input is Luckys Bar w/o the apostrophe, it doesn't find the result. Same with slashes or dashes.

What is the best approach to accomplishing this?

**PHP - Search Statement**

```
public function search($search_input) {
   $response = DB::table(self::$table)
          ->select(array(
            'ID',
            'Signup_Date',
            'Business_Name'
        ))
        ->where('Business_Name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search_input.'%')
        ->order_by('Signup_Date', 'desc')
        ->get();
   return $response;
}
```

Using Laravel 3, yes I know it is outdated, we have plans to upgrade, but this is a current issue that needs fixing. https://laravel3.veliovgroup.com/docs/database/fluent

Comment: '*I know it is outdated, we have plans to upgrade, but this is a current issue that needs fixing.*' - Heh, I've heard this before and oddly enough another issue cropped up which delayed it. Considering Laravel is on 5.7 now, you can surely expect it to have patched many major security security concerns from earlier versions.

Comment: What is actually stored in the db? Is the the literal `'` or is the the corresponding entity?

Comment: You could use `HTML::entities` on your query.

Comment: Sorry, Yes, in the DB it would have Lucky's Bar.

Comment: Ensure the apostrophe is `'` and not something else as was the case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47805167/laravel-query-using-like-does-not-return-any-result).

Comment: @GiBiT09 How about going for substrings and using `IN` operator in your query, for example , if user typed `Luckys Bar`, then try with `L`,`Lu`,`Luc`,`Luck`,`Lucky` etc. So, special characters won't hinder in your search. Substrings would be those starting from first character, so you will have `n` substrings for a user-entered string of length `n`. The only disadvantage is you would get a lot of not-so-relevant results as well.

Comment: @vivek_23 I see what your saying and it would make sense that sounds like it would be very slow with massive amount of data.

Comment: @GiBiT09 Fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way, which might be unacceptably slow, is

`WHERE REPLACE(field, "'", "") LIKE 'tam osha%"`

where in the DB it is stored as `Tam O'Shanter`.